# What monster attacks have "Miss" outcomes?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, attack

I was looking at the [piercer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/piercer) and noticed that it's attack not only has a *Hit* outcome, but a *Miss* line as well that is both fun and fits the attack. As far as I can tell, the piercer is the only creature like this in the *Monster Manual*.

What other monsters have specified Miss outcomes for their attacks/actions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### You're right that *Miss* outcomes are uncommon

I've found a few more using [the search function on DnD Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=miss&f=monsters&c=monsters), but there aren't many.

In addition to the [Piercer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/piercer), there's also:

- A [**Kobold Inventor**](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/kobold-inventor) which has a *Miss* effect when it throws a Green Slime Pot as part of its Weapon Invention action. Published in *Volo's Guide to Monsters*.
- [**Zorak Lightdrinker**](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/zorak-lightdrinker) who has a *Hit or Miss* effect after making a weapon attack. Published in *Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage*.
- A [**Fluxcharger**](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/fluxcharger) which has a *Hit or Miss* effect when it uses its Arc Lightning action. Published in *Guildmasters' Guide to Ravnica*.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I've only used the site enough to see the paywall. Knowing the search bypasses those is useful.

Comment: @raithyn: Yep, the search results are drawn from all sources, including those you don't own, and the preview below each result is visible even without owning it - you do need to own the content to see the full source page, though.

Comment: Or you can search for the text at the end of the snippet and get a couple more words. Rinse and repeat. :-)

Answer (score 11):

The only other one I could find with a "Miss:" result was the [kobold inventor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/kobold-inventor)'s Green Slime Pot:

> Hit: The target is covered in a patch of green slime. Miss: A patch of green slime covers a randomly determined 5-foot-square section of wall or floor within 5 feet of the target.

I used this [D&D Beyond search](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=miss&f=monsters&c=monsters) to find this. Note there is also 
[Zorak Lightdrinker](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/zorak-lightdrinker) and [Fluxcharger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/fluxcharger) which have a different "Hit or Miss:" option.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I've only used the site enough to see the paywall. Knowing the search bypasses those is useful.